# Matrix factorization overview

Tags: linear-algebra

Does this hold?

> All $\lambda_i$ are different ⇒  eigenvectors are linearly independent.

I am, for the sake of matrix factorization such as svd, $QR$ and $UDU^H$ interested in the relationship between eigenvalues and eigenvectors (also maybe eigenspaces).

I have not got a full overview of this yet. We have learned about:

- LU
- QR
- $SDS^{-1}$ (eigenvectors in S, eigenvalues in D).
- $UDU^H$ where U is unitar and D diagnoal
- svd

And I wonder about how they fit toghether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this holds, consider any two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ of some matrix $A$ (which could be the matrix representation of some linear operator) with associated (coordinate vectors of) eigenvectors $X_1, X_2$. Suppose $a_1X_1+a_2X_2=0$. Now multiply this equation first by $\lambda_1$, then on the left by $A$, and you get \begin{equation}a_1\lambda_1X_1+a_2\lambda_1X_2=0\end{equation}\begin{equation}a_1\lambda_1X_1+a_2\lambda_2X_2=0\end{equation}Subtract these two equations from each other and you have \begin{equation}a_2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)X_2=0.\end{equation} Since $X_2$ is nonzero and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are distinct, $a_2=0$ and then $a_1=0$. So $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly independent.

If you want to read an excellent overview of factorization, see this: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081089108818053#.UyChPtzZX1o